# adding a .gif to a graphics component?

Tags: java

I have a little issue here.
Me and a group of friends have created a some what minesweeper clone and need to create an animation to place over a "bomb" when its been clicked and activated but nothing happens. This is slight code taken from a highly voted stack overflow post but it somehow doesn't work. Regards.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Mine extends Tile {

public Mine(boolean isMine, boolean isHidden) {
    // Always set hidden to false as Mine is a visible tile.
    // Always set mine to true as Mine is a mine.
    super(true, false);
}

public void render(Graphics g, int x, int y) {

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
     Image icon = null;
    try {
        icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSnus.gif")).getImage();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      g.drawImage(icon, 0, 0, 50, 50, this);


}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Please specify the problem occurring instead of making us go through whole post and try figure out stuff...

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh literally nothing works.. it opens the jframe with nothing displayed

Comment: You're probably going to want to include your Tile class source

Comment: @Confiqure literally all im trying to do is display an image

Comment: I understand your question, but having this additional source might let us target the problem much better